# How to use dart pub serve alongside another webserver sdk

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'am new to dart. I try to run a dart client and an appengine SDK server. The appengine SDK for Python serves dynamic HTML with jinja.

During development I like to use dart pub serve to serve the dart code and the app engine SDK to serve HTML and CSS assets.

I used stagehand to setup web-simple dart in my Pycharm app engine project. But I could not figure out how to serve the HTML and CSS assests from the appengine SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special provided by Dart for this scenario.

Usually it's suggested to use a proxy server that forwards requests for Dart resources to `pub serve` and everything else to your custom server (appengine, ...). This can be done with a few lines of code using the `shelf`, `shelf_proxy`, and `shelf_static` packages.

Dart is moving to `bazel` as build tool instead of `pub serve` (limited preview available). They might take a different approach with or after the switch.

Comment: Ok. I will read into this. If I understand you well: I have to put a proxy server in the middle to serve all requests and you suggest to use a dart proxy server which will also be served by pub serve. So pub serve will serve everything except the assets which will be proxied to the appengine SDK.

Comment: "in the middle to serve all requests " - yes. The proxy would be a command line script unrelated to `pub serve`, it would just forward to `pub serve` when Dart resources are requested by the browser. You can also use `Nginx` with a few forwarding rules.

Comment: Thnx. I use windows 10 and will try Nginx.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Excellent! Other than [dart-lang/bazel](https://github.com/dart-lang/bazel) and [dart-lang/rules_dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/rules_dart) can you provide a reference where I can learn more about `bazel` replacing `pub serve`? We use `bazel` for all of our compiles so this is ideal from my perspective.

Comment: They stalled the bazel support for outside Google. The last comment I saw about this was because of the lack of Windows support from Bazel, but that seemed to have changed. I saw some development activities continually in the related repositories, but I haven seen any docs.